# Importing Date field from flat file to sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, import

I have a flat file which has dates like "DD/MM/YYYY" format. When I import it using the import wizard, I chose the the source as dt_date, but after the import the dates for the fields are i this format YYYY-DD-MM and
YYYY-MM-DD. Why is this so?

Comment: They aren't "in a format", date and time data types (such as `date`) have no format; they are stored as binary values. It's your presentation layer that needs to define the format when it receives the data from the RDBMS.

Comment: Thank you so much! I managed to convert them